# How can I make waitbar in MATLAB modal

Tags: matlab, user-interface, progress-bar, modal-dialog

I am working on a MATLAB GUI where I have to show a progress bar. I have two problems with the `waitbar` function:

1. I want to make the progress bar modal, so that user can't do any other thing on the GUI while the progress bar is shown.
2. There is the minimize button and the close button at the top right corner of the bar (pretty much like any other window). If you press the close button, the progress bar closes, I want this button to be hidden or disabled so that the user can't close the bar.

How can I implement these behaviours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
plot(sin(1:100))
h = waitbar(0, 'Please wait...');
set(h, 'WindowStyle','modal', 'CloseRequestFcn','');
for i=1:10
    waitbar(i/10, h);
    pause(.5)
end
delete(h)
```

[image: screenshot]

By setting `CloseRequestFcn` to empty string, clicking the close button will do nothing. You just have to wait for the loop to finish.

Note that you can still hit <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> to kill the running computation (which I think is a good thing, you don't want to annoy the user after all!)

Answer (score 0):

For number 1 there you should look into threading within Matlab.  You'll likely need the parallel computing toolbox to gain access to the necessary functions.  You can find out more [here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/f3-6010.html)

As far as number 2 goes.  You should be able to override the close function in the code for the GUI.

It would be something along the lines of this:

```
function MyWaitBar_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

delete(hObject); % This of course deletes the object and we don't want this.
```

So you would just leave the function empty.  But don't forget to close it at some point!

Comment: I forgot to mention, but you would have to put whatever calculation/process the GUI triggers for the waitbar on the other thread.  I'm pretty sure you can then allow for continued use of the GUI while that is being processed.